# Should Drupal Commerce questions be tagged 7?

Tags: discussion

Based on @Clive's comment [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28697/drupal-7-integrate-commerce-fields-into-user-profile#comment28102_28697), I'd like to know more about how we're supposed to be tagging Commerce-related questions.  My initial thought was that since Commerce is only for D7 and is not a candidate for backport to D6, Commerce-related questions should be tagged 7 as well as Commerce.  Also, when Commerce is released for Drupal 8, it will probably be significantly different and many of the old D7 answers will not apply; hence, having that information available (i.e., that the questions related to the D7 version) will be helpful.

Should Commerce questions right now always be tagged 7?  Never be tagged 7?  Sometime's be tagged 7?

Comment: My thinking was that as Commerce is only available for Drupal 7 it would be redundant to add [tag:7] to it, but now that you mention Drupal 8 I can see why it's not quite so clear cut (or at least might not be further down the line). For the record I'd personally like to see every single question on the site tagged with [tag:6]/[tag:7]/[tag:8] as I think it's very useful; there are very differing opinions on this though :)

Comment: I think it would be good to get this agreed across the board (i.e. not just relating to the commerce module). Today alone I've already rejected 5 or 6 suggested edits where the question was re-tagged with the version number, when the OP had already stated version number somewhere in the question; it would be nice to have a definitive yes or no answer as to whether this is definitely the 'right' thing to do

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely like to reach consensus with everyone else about this.  When I edit questions, I've been doing the opposite-- removing "Drupal 7" from the question title and adding the 7 tag.  I just want to make the site easier to use/search; I definitely don't want to be fighting against other editors and causing people trouble.

Comment: Tag everything with version. Cleaner and allows to search for questions to answer based on the drupal version. At least that's my personal view on this.